# JSONPath or JMESPath filtering against another expression

Tags: javascript, jsonpath, jmespath

I am struggling to find a way to filter nodes against another expression rather than a string or number. I have looked at the specs for both [JSONPath](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath) and [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org) and find a little info on the inability to do this the way I have been trying.

**JSONPath**

"*With JSONPath square brackets operate on the object or array addressed by the previous path fragment. Indices always start by 0*"

I have found JSONPath plus which has a @parent property but it only appear to go up to immediate parent and I need to access from root (or work up the ladder)

**JMESPath**

The specs seem to indicate a filter should be `expression compare expression` but I cannot get it to work. There is a semi related [issue](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.js/issues/22) and a note on [current_node](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#current-node) though it's a little unclear to me.

End of the day I am trying to achieve this:

**Data**

```
{ 
  level: 20,
  items: [{
    qty: 20,
    id: '123'
  }, {
    qty: 30,
    id: '234'
 }]
}
```

**Expression:**

```
$.items[?(@.qty==$.level)]
```

**Expectations**

To fetch all the items with a `qty` that matches `level`.

Suggestions on to achieve this? I am looking at expanding the JSONPath implementation for myself as it seems the only way. I am not as versed in JMESPath which I just discovered so perhaps there is actually a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Well the fantastic author of [JSONPath plus](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath) added the @root feature right away.

So now:

```
$.items[?(@.qty==@root.level)] // Could use @parent.level for shallow stuff too
```

Comment: Anything on JMESPath too, please?

Comment: @Victor I stopped looking at that one so not sure. Along the way I also discovered JSONata which might be of interest. I switched over to it myself.

Comment: I was looking for something that offers implementations both for Node and PHP. You have any idea, please?

Comment: Sorry I do not - I would think xpath though since thats pretty standard. Must be decent xpath php libs